# position fixed not working on sticky menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added this class ".sticky" by javascript to the nav but sticky menu not working correctly.

```
.sticky {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 100;
border-top: 0;
-webkit-transform: none;
transform: none;
}
```

javascript code

```
//sticky menu
 var stickyNavTop = $('.main-navbar').offset().top;
 var stickyNav = function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
        $('.main-navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main-navbar').removeClass('sticky'); 
    }
};
stickyNav();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickyNav();
});
```

can you please check the page 
http://www.chainreaction.ae/alayam/

thank you

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle of this?

Comment: for some reason the fixed position not working on the website, if I make a JSFiddle for it. it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css:

```
.scotch-panel-canvas {
    transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: This will break the off canvas menu, is there any other solution?

Comment: I want to some time

Answer (score 1):

Please remove inline styles from the  `scotch-panel-canvas` div then it works fine...

remove this style: `style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden; transition: all 300ms ease;"`

i don't how this inline css coming from but you should remove this. I think this style coming from some jquery. When u remove this code it works fine...

and also increase the `z-index` value

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: fixed;` and `top: 0px;` should be enough.

Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/yp8HK/1/

Comment: thank you but you did not answer my question, why it is not working on my page?